# Folder Redirection for user logging into workstation and server

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

We have 4 admins that administer multiple Windows 2012r2 servers.

Our IT Manager has asked that we change the way we log on to servers now for auditing reasons after an ex admin went rogue.

We have our domain accounts that we log into our workstations with - and he wants us to now log into the servers with these accounts rather than the domain admin account.

There is a Folder Redirection GPO setup though for the Desktop, Documents and Pictures.

We need this kept in place for the workstations but do not want the GPO to take affect when an admin uses his domain account to log into the server.

How is best to achieve this?

Reading around it appears that Loopback Processing would achieve this as it would basically not read the user config part of the GPO if linked into our Servers OU?

Anybody au fait with Loopback Processing and could help me out a little?

Comment: Admins should have separate administrator accounts which they only use if doing admin work. Daily work should be done with a user account. Do not apply folder redirection to administrator accounts.

Comment: Should have and will have are complete separate entities with our IT Manager! :)

Comment: He wants us to use our own accounts and doesn't want us to have separate accounts for Admin work. Why? His prerogative. So is it possible to actually do this and exclude the folder redirection from applying when logging into the server? Thanks

Comment: This proposal is, at best, security theater, and won't actually achieve what he wants to achieve.  I'd push back and try to get him to understand the absolutely 0 impact this change would have, before doing any work to implement something useless.